# Is there a way to allow scripts but block top navigation on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

In the following example, `Foo.html` lives in `/tmp/` and is accessed locally without a web server, while `Bar.html` lives in `/var/www/` and is served by Apache.

This configuration causes `Foo.html` and `Bar.html` to be on different origins, but it is important for making the example reproducible.

**Foo.html**

```
<html>
<script>
foo = function() {
alert("foo says hi");
};
</script>
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts" width="200" height="300" src="http://localhost/Bar.html" onLoad="foo();" /> 
</html>
```

**Bar.html**

```
<html>
<script>
if(top.location != self.location){
    parent.location = self.location;
}
</script>
<form action="about:blank" method="post">
<input type="text" name="destination_username" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</html>
```

In Firefox (V27 on Linux), if `Foo.html` is loaded, `Bar.html` is able to escape the frame (become the top frame) despite the lack of `allow-top-navigation` in the `sandbox` attribute.

In Chrome, if `Foo.html` is loaded, `Bar.html` cannot escape the frame.

It seems that `sandbox` is implemented incorrectly in Firefox. *Is there some HTML attribute or JS hack which will `allow-scripts` while not permitting `top-navigation` in Firefox as well?*